# Remove cell padding in nested p:dataTable

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I want to set the cell padding in the inner table to `0px` or remove the border. Here you see a simple example of my `dataTable`. I attached a screenshot below. The padding I want to remove is marked red, but I want to keep the horizontal cell borders (marked green).

```
<p:dataTable id="mandantTable" var="customer"
        value="#{preferences.customers}">
        <p:column headerText="Mandant">
            <h:outputText value="#{customer.name}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Seite">
            <p:dataTable id="siteTable" var="site" value="#{customer.sites}">
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{site.siteName}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

[image]

Comment: you know using firefox/chrome developer tools could make your life easier when debuging css? just inspect the element (right click on it -> Inspect), and on the right side of the window, you'll get all the css properties, and they're yours to play with.